# jQuery scrolling to div on css change (sticky nav)

Tags: jquery, css, fixed, sticky

I'm using my own code below to try and set a sticky nav.

Its working, but whenever it changes the div to fixed, the browser automatically scrolls to it. This means the browser cannot scroll any further than where the original nav bar is.

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stickNavOffset = $('#nav').offset().top;

    function sticky() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > stickNavOffset-1) {
            $('#nav').css({position:'fixed',left:'auto'});
        } else {
            $('#nav').css({position:'relative',left:'auto'});
        }
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        sticky();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem you describe. I made a quick [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nate/LTznp/) with your code (always a good idea when posting a question). Does it show the problem you're having? If not, could you adjust it so that it does?

Comment: Yes and no. You're fiddle is right, and it works fine. But on my site It automatically scrolls to the top. I've tried it an my laptop, and the issue does not occur.
On my desktop the issue occurs even in incognito window. COuld it be a browser issue?

Comment: It may be related to browser behavior, but it's still something you have to solve. :) So: one of the basic techniques of troubleshooting is to isolate the element that's causing your problem. We've got a Fiddle set up that works fine, and a site that has a problem. So it's time to start adding more potential elements from your site to the fiddle until you can reproduce your problem. Once you've isolated the component that's causing the issue, you're 3/4 of the way to the solution.

Comment: Btw, making sticky elements is a little bit complicated: you need to account for the space the element formerly took up on your page, for one thing, so there's no jump in the content when it switches to position: fixed. Also, it's very important to have a throttle on your scroll function for [performance reasons](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/). It might be worth using one of the many plugins out there to do this, unless you're doing it on your own for learning purposes, which is great.

Comment: I've managed to break the fiddle, without adding any extra plugins [See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Coysh/LTznp/2/)
Taking the left css attribute from the jQuery manages to break it within the fiddle.
Strange, because the site has the left attributes and is still broken.

Comment: Also, the bug only happens when the window is fully maximized (Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem happens when your content is just the right height that when your sticky element is set to `position: relative`, it's high enough to vertically scroll, and when removed from the document flow, the content is no longer high enough to force scrolling.

So when it switches to fixed, you snap back to the top because your document's not tall enough to scroll, which sets your sticky element to `position: relative` again, which brings back the scroll bar.

You can test this by just adding more content to your page - if it's tall enough that even without the sticky element, it'll still scroll, you won't have this problem.

You should notice *another* problem, though, which is that your content jumps a little bit. Actually, it jumps exactly the height of your sticky element, which is suddenly no longer there.

That's what I meant in my comment when I said you'd have to account for that space with your code. In the past, when I've created sticky elements, I create a cloned placeholder element that I leave set to `position: relative` that I leave in place so that the height doesn't jump.

Comment: Perfect! For those interested I added a
`<div id="navfiller">&nbsp;</div>`
Before the nav, with display: none.
When the sticky nav is set to position: fixed; I show the navfiller, and hide it when the position is set to relative.